# In 星の王子さま, what is this 六つのとき?

Tags: translation

In the first page, this is written:

> 六{むっ}つのとき、原始林{げんしりん}のことを書{か}いた「ほんとうにあった話{はなし}」という、本{ほん}の中{なか}で、すばらしい絵{え}を見{み}たことがあります。

I don't have the English version, but the Brazilian version says the equivalent of:

> Once upon a time, when I was 6 years old, I saw in a book about the Virgin Forest, Real Stories, a impressive drawing.

Would it be correct if I said something like 私が六歳のとき?

Comment: My copy has a different Japanese translation: 僕が六歳だったときのことだ。

Answer (score 6):

> (私が) [六歳]{ろくさい}のとき...
>   (私が) [六]{むっ}つのとき...

Both are correct.

「～歳」 can be used for all ages, and 「～つ」, for ages from 1 to 9, as in 「ひとつ、ふたつ、みっつ、よっつ、いつつ、むっつ、ななつ、やっつ、ここのつ」, and 「とお」 for 10. 「～つ」 is more casual/informal, and can sound a bit more childish than 「～歳」 (We use 「お幾つですか？」 for adults, too, though).

> Adult (toward a little boy): 「ぼく、[幾]{いく}つ？」/ 「ぼく、[何歳]{なんさい}？」
>   Child: 「[３]{みっ}つ。」/「[３才]{さんさい}。」

Comment: I see. So, also the answer depends on the questions as well, as in you use 歳 when asked 何歳 and use つ when asked 幾つ?

Comment: @Patrick It's fine to reply with 歳 when asked 幾つ, eg 「ぼく、いくつ？」--「５歳。」/ 「おいくつで（いらっしゃいま）すか？」-- 「２８歳です。」 or even without 歳 (over 11~): 「おいくつですか？/ お年は？ etc.」--「２８です。」