# What is independent form of numeral 10?

Tags: counters, numbers

An old Dover grammar-book of Japanese shows it to be *to* (it has no kana but I assume it's と), but Wikipedia shows *to̅* (とお). Which one is correct?

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62469/in-%e6%98%9f%e3%81%ae%e7%8e%8b%e5%ad%90%e3%81%95%e3%81%be-what-is-this-%e5%85%ad%e3%81%a4%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8d/62480#62480 ?

Answer (score 3):

It is 「とお」 as explained in the Q&A I linked to above.  That is how "10" is read in the original Japanese way (prior to our dramatic encounter with the Chinese).

Listen to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgvUPbPSY2g&t=) from 0:25 and you will see that it is the ***elongated*** 「とお」 and not the regular-length 「と」.

In actual words, however, the kanji 「十」 are read both ways.  Which one to use depends on the word.

「とお」： 「十日{とおか}」 ("10th day of the month")

「と」： 「十度{とたび}」 ("10 times")

My Favorite: 「十月十日{とつきとおか}」

The first 「十」 is read 「と」 and the second, 「とお」.  This is how we figuratively and rhythmically describe the normal length of human pregnancy before delivery -- "10 months and 10 days".

For the date "October 10th", however, 「十月十日」 is read 「**じゅう**がつ**とお**か」.  As far as pronunciation, the first 「十」 is Chinese-influenced, but the second 「十」 is originally Japanese.

Comment: >>  That is how "10" is read in the original
Rather, [towo], とを in the old orthography.